laravel do not connect to DataBase in docker
I can't connect to a Laravel database running via Docker
my docker-compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:
   nginx:
     image: "nginx:stable-alpine"
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     volumes:
       - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
       - ./src:/var/www/laravel
     depends_on:
       -mysql
       - php
   php:
     build:
       context: dockerfiles
       dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
     volumes:
       - ./src:/var/www/laravel
   mysql:
     image: mysql:8.0
     ports:
       - "3316:3306"
     environment:
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel_db
       - MYSQL_USER=laravel
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

volumes:
   db_data:

my .env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3316
DB_DATABASE=laravel_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

set DB_HOST container name in docker
set DB_PORT port from docker-compose.yml
installed DB_DATABASE from docker-compose.yml
Connection through the console is fine
but it doesn’t work through Laravel
I can’t figure out where the error is?

What error message do you get? And does your Laravel app try to connect to the database immediately on start? The database needs a little time to get ready.

"HY000" is a general server error (see Server Error Codes and Messages in MySQL docs).
"2002" is MySQL Client Error Code meaning "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" (see (Client Error Codes and Messages in MySQL docs).

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses:

DB_PORT=3306

The port should be the one the container uses internally, not the exposed one since you're using the container name as the host.

unfortunately it didn't help
I tried making the hostname 127.0.0.1 and then 3316 it worked
